# XAMPP Ubuntu - How would i import Employees Database into Mysql

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am new to linux and programming so any help is appreciated...

I have downloaded the Employees sample database from: [MySql Sample Database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/)
It has given me a .tar.bz2 file type, When i open phpMyadmin and go to import database and select the file i get error code #1064  upon upload.

I am not sure on how to proceed, so how would i upload this file so i can use it in mysql on Xampp.

Comment: RTFD? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/employees-installation.html

Comment: I have seen that, however i do not understand it. Which is half my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions I linked in my comment may not make sense to a new Linux user. To explain:

```
shell> tar -xjf $HOME/Downloads/employees_db-full-1.0.6.tar.bz2
shell> cd employees_db/
```

are two command-line instructions to be issued in a Terminal shell to 1) unpack the .tar archive, and 2) change the shell working directory to that of the extracted archive contents. The `shell>` notation is only an indicator for whatever Terminal shell is being used. You'll see `user@host:~$` for example when you open a Terminal session.

The instructions presume that you downloaded the archive to your user Downloads directory, as it references to `$HOME/Downloads`. If you've placed the archive in a different location, you will need to direct the first command to that location.

You would only need to edit the `employees.sql` file if your MySQL installation if not using the InnoDB storage engine, which is the default for standard installations of MySQL.

The last command - `shell> mysql -t < employees.sql` - tells the `mysql` process to import the data in the `employees.sql` file, creating a new database with the information the .sql file contains.